# Table textboxes losing value on postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have some code that I found online to add a new row to a table dynamically http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/29/faq-dynamically-adding-rows-in-asp-table-on-button-click.aspx . The row gets added and all previous data is gone. From the comments it seems like a lot of people had this issue.

ASPX

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMaterial" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName ="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="tbMaterials" runat="server" GridLines="Both" Visible="false">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>Qty</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Material</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Cost</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Price</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Total</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

VB

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Private numOfRows As Integer = 1

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ViewState("RowsCount") = 1
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub addRow(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'adds the column row once we know the header row is there
    If ViewState("RowsCount") IsNot Nothing Then
        tbMaterials.Visible = True
        numOfRows = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState("RowsCount").ToString)
        GenerateTable(numOfRows)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GenerateTable(rowsCount As Integer)
    'Creat the Table and Add it to the Page

    Dim table As Table = tbMaterials

    'The number of Columns to be generated
    Const colsCount As Integer = 5
    'You can changed the value of 3 based on you requirements

    ' Now iterate through the table and add your controls
    For i As Integer = 0 To rowsCount - 1
        Dim row As New TableRow()

        For j As Integer = 0 To colsCount - 1
            Dim cell As New TableCell()
            Dim tb As New TextBox()

            ' Set a unique ID for each TextBox added
            tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i.ToString + "Col_" + j.ToString
            ' Add the control to the TableCell
            cell.Controls.Add(tb)
            ' Add the TableCell to the TableRow
            row.Cells.Add(cell)
        Next

        ' And finally, add the TableRow to the Table
        table.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    'Set Previous Data on PostBacks
    SetPreviousData(rowsCount, colsCount)
    'Sore the current Rows Count in ViewState
    rowsCount += 1
    ViewState("RowsCount") = rowsCount
End Sub
Private Sub SetPreviousData(rowsCount As Integer, colsCount As Integer)
    Dim table As Table = tbMaterials
    If table IsNot Nothing Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To rowsCount - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To colsCount - 1
                'Extracting the Dynamic Controls from the Table
                Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(table.Rows(i).Cells(j).FindControl("TextBoxRow_" + i.ToString + "Col_" + j.ToString), TextBox)
                'Use Request objects for getting the previous data of the dynamic textbox
                tb.Text = Request.Form("TextBoxRow_" + i.ToString + "Col_" + j.ToString)
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check using view source from browser if ID you are using to get form variable are the same as name of name of variable you are using in tb.Text = Request.Form("TextBoxRow_" + i.ToString + "Col_" + j.ToString). As we can not use id for request variables.